# Routing between Two Host-Only Networks

Tags: routing, nat, vmware-workstation, static-routes

I have two routers on VMWare workstation, **Router01** and **Router02**, both are set up as Host Only Networks.

I need to route between the two networks, so that from **Router01** I can ping the *public endpoint* of **Router02** and vice versa ?

Private Endpoint ~~~~~~~~~~ Public Endpoint

192.168.10.5 ---- **Router01** ---- 192.168.81.129 ---- ? ---- 192.168.159.128 ---- **Router02** ---- 192.168.11.5

**Router01** and **Router02** are Ubuntu Virtual Machines set up using IPTables to simulate different NAT environments. My end game is to send messages from 192.168.10.x network and have it reach 192.168.159.128, to test hole punching techniques.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How do I route between 192.168.81.129 and 192.168.159.128 so that 192.168.81.129 can ping 192.168.159.128 and vice versa ?

Comment: Questions end with "?".

Comment: The obvious answer would be 'set up routing' but you've not mentioned what type of router you have now do you give the impression of knowing what you're doing - and that's kind of one of our requirements on this site, it's not for learners as we make very clear when you sign up.

Comment: I am a software student, and need to set up this environment for testing, no I am not an expert so can you please redirect me to somewhere I can post this question ? The routers are setup already they are done using Ubuntu IPTables to simulate different Cone NATs. What I am trying to do is from the host machine make the two endpoints know of each other as if they where on the internet

Comment: @Chopper3 He wants to use probably the linux command line route commands.

Comment: On unix.stackexchange.com you will get what you want.

Comment: The Host machine is Windows not Linux

Comment: Windows has also a `route` command. I suggest to try http://superuser.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows host with vmware workstation, you will need to create a network and add both routers 1 & 2 to the same network or same switch so that one can reach other. In this way, routers would be able to broadcast their routing table and be able to forward packets to destination.